# sparse matrix from triplet

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

With eigen (c++) i want to have a similar result as Matlab's one :

```js
 % Matlab code: Create a 1500-by-1500 sparse matrix from the triplets i, j, 
            and v 
 i = [900 1000];
   j = [900 1000];
   v = [10 100];
   S = sparse(i,j,v,1500,1500)

   %result
    S =

 (900,900)     10
 (1000,1000)   100
```

I want to do the same thing in C++, i saw in different posts that we can handle sparse matrices with Eigen Library, but i didn't really understand how to do this. Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your current best trial to it? You need to provide some code of your own to get help in fixing it. See [ask] is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a vector of triplets

```
typedef Eigen::Triplet<int> Trip;
std::vector<Trip> trp;
```

Create the triplets

```
trp.push_back(Trip(900,900,10)); // (index, index, value)
trp.push_back(Trip(1000,1000,100));
```

Assign them to the sparse Eigen matrix

```
int rows, cols;
rows = cols = 1500;
Eigen::SparseMatrix<int> A(rows,cols);

A.setFromTriplets(trp.begin(), trp.end());
```

Print the entire (dense) matrix

```
std::cout << A << std::endl;
```

or print just the indices and values

```
std::cout << "Row\tCol\tVal" <<std::endl;
for (int k=0; k < A.outerSize(); ++k)
{
    for (SparseMatrix<int>::InnerIterator it(A,k); it; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it.row() << "\t"; // row index
        std::cout << it.col() << "\t"; // col index (here it is equal to k)
        std::cout << it.value() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I want to understand either if possible. Why you have assigned the values in that order to 2 triplets? why don't we use 3 triplets? i think i still don't understand the structure of the Triplet.
How can i visualize the result as the Matlab's result ?

Comment: An [Eigen::Triplet](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Triplet.html) is a simple structure that holds a single `i,j,v` set. If you wanted 32 elements in your matrix, you'd create 32 Triplets. If in your example you had a vector for each `i`, `j`, and `v`, here you have the transpose.

Comment: Ok, i've done that, but  i'm still confuse. Sparse matrix has the aim to not store zero values. Here the matrix A stores zeros values.. i don't know if you see what i mean ?

Comment: `A` doesn't store the zero values. When `<<` Eigen prints the entire Matrix. I'll update my post to show how to print just the triplets.

Comment: Ok thanks, i understand. i'm trying to translate a matlab code (matlab coder does not translate all the functions of Matlab...). i'll be back if i'm stuck

Comment: Hi ananass, Are you able integrate eigen code with matlab. Please share.